# angular 2 - Property 'skipLast' does not exist on type 'Observable<number>'

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

i'm using Behavior Subject in a angular 2 component and i want the second emitted value before last one , [RxJs document](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/skiplast.html) says i should use skipLast method on my stream to ignore them but i get an error while using it that says :

Property 'skipLast' does not exist on type 'Observable'

Angular version : 2.3.1
Rx.js version : 5.0.3

here is my code :

```
import 'rxjs'
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject'

@Component({
  ...
})

export class FilesComponent {
  folderId: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(0)

  constructor() {
    this.folderId.skipLast(2).subscribe(
      value => { console.log(value) }
    )
  }    

  clickHandler(fileId: number): void {
      this.folderId.next(fileId)
  }

}
```

Comment: Where do you get that there should be a `skipLast` operator?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer as i already said i read that from rx documentation . can you suggest a way to implement this despite of that this is no longer available in Rx 5 ?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I find this rather weird that it was supported at all. How can you know that an event is the 3rd-last before the observable has completed. I think this would mean to withhold 2 events until a new one arrives, so you would always have 2 outstanding events until the observable completes. What is the use case for that?

Comment: i'm writing a file manager and every directory has an id so navigation should be implemented using that id in case of going deeper into directory there is no problem but when implementing back button this becomes the problem ( i need the grandfather id to navigate one level up in the tree ) i think a good solution is using an array and cache the directory id that user has navigated and when clicking back delete last two id's and get files with id of last item in array but i think it would be very nice that i could implement this using streams.

Comment: I see, but no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

skip last operator is now added to RxJS 5 https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/2316

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/skipLast'
```

Actually, there is no `skipLast` operator.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/eb462bf8836d1bc27db5d11a9ea7cb4fa4b90f19/MIGRATION.md

> skipLast  | No longer implemented